# How to avoid stepping into 3rd party code in Visual Studio

Tags: debugging, visual-c++-2008

I am working with fairly complex code that is working with several 3rd part libraries. When I want to keep on stepping over (F10) I sometimes end up in 3rd party assembly code. If I deselect the option to go automatically into disassembly, it complains that the source code is not available. What I want to happen in this situation is for Visual Studio to step over all the 3rd party code and break as soon as it finds code with source file (most likely my project). Any way this behaviour can be enabled?

**Note:** I am working with unmanaged code